# Нахождение минимального числа в матрице DataGridView, ошибка "заданное приведение является недопустимым

Tags: c#, datagridview, min

не торопитесь пожалуйста кидать мне ссылки на подобные вопросы, сначала прочитайте. Код который раньше работал как часы, теперь выдает ошибку, мне надо найти минимальное число в матрице, и VS19 выдает "Заданное приведение является недопустимым". В другой программе с таким же кодом всё работает. Подскажите как исправить.
Код, который работает:

```
int maxX = int.MinValue;
        int maxY = int.MinValue;
        int l = 0, k = 0, m = 0, n = 0, fx, ay;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvX.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dgvX.RowCount; j++)
            {
                if ((int)dgvX[i, j].Value > maxX)
                {
                    maxX = (int)dgvX[i, j].Value;
                    l = i;
                    k = j;
                }
                if ((int)dgvX[i, j].Value < 0)
                {
                    dgvX[i, j].Value = maxX;
                }
            }
        }
```

Код, который не работает:

```
int min = int.MaxValue;
        for(int i =0;i<dgv.ColumnCount;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<dgv.RowCount;j++)
            {
                if( min>(int)dgv[i,j].Value)
                {
                    min = Convert.ToInt32(dgv[i, j].Value);
                    MessageBox.Show(min.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Я вот смотрю и не понимаю в чем разница, помогите.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: скорее всего ему не нравится явное приведение типов...попробуйте использовать класс `Convert`

Comment: И посмотрите в дебаге, когда ошибка вылетает чему равно ваше `dvg[i,j].Value`

Comment: Виталий, очень странно но ошибка вылетает на [7,7], это последняя ячейка таблицы [7,7]

Comment: Я использую конверт if( min>Convert.ToInt32(dgv[i,j].Value)) и теперь вылетает "входная строка имела неверный формат

Comment: Ставьте точку останова, и смотрите почему у строки не тот формат

Comment: Я понял, у меня по алгоритму [0,0] всегда пустое, потому ему не нравится, надо сделать чтобы он искал среди заполненных ячеек

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться `int.TryParse`, чтобы понять, можно ли то. что у вас, распаристь в число. Например

```
int min = int.MaxValue;
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.ColumnCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dgv.RowCount; j++)
    {
        int v = 0;          
        if (int.TryParse(dgv[i, j].Value.ToString(), out v))
        if (min > v)
        {
            min = v;
            MessageBox.Show(min.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```